# how to parse jsonArray in android?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I got a JSON and I'm trying to parse and sort scores based on values. I could not even parse it. Below is my JSON response.

```
[
      {"scores":
        { "a":1.460211E-17,
          "b":3.808661E-20,
          "c":3.07329371E-14,
          "d":1.02141569E-17,
          "e":1,
          "f":6.26432543E-12,
          "g":3.75437664E-14,
          "h":1.877707E-21
        },
      "rectangle":
       { "left":142,
         "width":882,
         "top":0,
         "height":848
       }
     }
    ]
```

I tried to convert the string as a JSONObject, but an error says it is a JSONArray.

```
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray jsonArray = reader.optJSONArray("scores");
```

getting error like

```
org.json.JSONException: Value of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

so I thought the value is already a JSON Array. I tried the following code ...

```
JSONArray jsonArray = reader.optJSONArray("scores");
```

AND

```
JSONArray cast = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("scores");
```

... but it throws the following error:

```
cannot resolve method optJSONArray()java.lang.String)
cannot resolve method getJSONArray()java.lang.String)
```

Comment: why did you downvote ? please tell me i can improve my question?

Comment: *Value of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject*  asked bazillion times ... learn json basics ... *cannot resolve method optJSONArray()java.lang.String)* <= obviously String(or whatever `jsonResponse` type is) has no `optJSONArray` method ...

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Comment: @Selvin Thakn you , but it says error says JSONArray so im calling json array also at first but editor tells me the last error

Comment: You can get enough knowledge from this link : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: @SuhasBachewar Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error `org.json.JSONException: Value of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject` clearly says that you are trying to parse a `JSONArray` to a `JSONObject`

Do this

```
JSONArray reader = new JSONArray(json);
JSONObject jsonArray = reader.getJSONObject(0).optJSONObject("scores"); // replace 0 with your own index
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. 
editors throws error like `optJSONObject (int) in JsonArray connot be Applied to (java.lang.String)`

Comment: oh yes, I missed something. Please try now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if, for example, you get your Json from a HTTP request:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost( "http://www.somepage.php" );

HttpParams mHttpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(mHttpParams, myConnectionTimeOut );
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(mHttpParams, myTimeOut);

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient( mHttpParams );
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( entity.getContent() ));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line = null;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line  );
}

JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("scores");

for( int i = 0; i < jsonArray .length(); i++ ) { 
    /* Do what you want here*/                                                          
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        JSONArray array= new JSONArray("your string");

        JSONObject object= array.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject
         scores=object.getJSONObject("scores");
        String [] subjects={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"};
        for(int i=0;i<subjects.length;i++){

            Log.e("TAG",scores.getString(subjects[i]));

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: yeah it works. how can i make it as loop rather than getting a,b,c?

Comment: I have updated answer see if it helps. Sine they are keys in a json object , you can only put your keys inside array and get all values from the json object in loop.